# AWS Code for S3 Upload file using embedded-C SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a file to an AWS S3 private bucket using [aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C), but without success.

First I tried upload a file using python and boto3 `upload_file` function, this was successful. Now because the embedded-C sdk requires a pre-signed URL's (boto3 doesn't) I have modified the python script not to call `upload_file` but only print the aws credentials and key to the screen.

Then I take these credentials, put in ~/.aws/credentials and generate a pre-signed URL using the presigned_urls_gen.py script of embedded-C sdk.

When I run the demo I am always getting the error:
`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

When I added some debug I saw that boto3 is doing something completly different then the upload example in embedded-C sdk. The example in embedded-C sdk is not even using sigv4 to sign anything or add security headers to the request.

How come the same upload procedure is so different in embedded-C sdk versus the boto3?

Comment: Did you copy the output of the python script to the proper demo_config.h file and rebuild the project?  Does the URL it creates work if you use curl?

Comment: @AnonCoward I copied the output of presigned_urls_gen.py to demo_project.h and that didn't work. I didn't try with CURL, I will search now how to generate upload to S3 with curl. You have a link to some instruction for CURL S3 upload maybe?

Comment: What is demo_project.h?  I see no such file in the embedded SDK.  Generally you just use something like `curl -v --upload-file filename.dat http://presigned.amazonaws.com/...`

Comment: @AnonCoward It gives me the same error. I think the problem is that the request needs to be signed because it's private bucket. I saw that in boto3 it added a md5 header and sigv4 signature. The code in embedded-C sdk does not do any of that...

Comment: The output of "presigned_urls_gen.py" is signed, that's kind of the point of that script.  It certainly works for me on a private bucket.  I'd be much more inclined to think something is wrong with your aws cli configuration, and you've specified the wrong AWS key.

Comment: @AnonCoward Here is what I do: I ask for credentials using my private key, cert and CA. I put those credentials into ~/.aws/credentials and generate URL using presigned_urls_gen.py. When I try to use the generatered URL it does not work (also the filename is not specified in the URL so I don't understand how it knows which filename to give it on server or which file to download)

Comment: That is very much not what the AWS signing process expects.  You should be creating and using [an AWS access key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) for use with any AWS API that expects an AWS access key, such as S3.